# Embed Video with VideoEmbedPlayer and Autoplay

Tags: 2013, video

I want to embed a video in a User Control within SharePoint 2013 (this has to work on IE8 at least).

I am currently using this piece of code:

```
<iframe src="https://mysite/_layouts/15/videoembedplayer.aspx?extSrc=theUrl.mp4&img=theThumbnail.jpg" 
        type="text/html" >
```

As you can see I am using `videoembedplayer.aspx` which seems to work with IE11 browser compatibility IE8 (I have yet to try it on a real IE8 browser).

However, I cannot find any documentation anywhere about this media player. I would like to make it play as soon as the page loads.

I tried with `autoplay=1` and `autoplay=true`, both won't work.

Any hints are welcome ; and if you've got a link to an actual documentation with all the possible parameters I'd gladly take it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used auto=1 to get the video play as soon as the page loads.

Also, if you are using the Sharepoint out of the box video type, you should be able to edit the embed configurations for the video and generate the code that way. See the "Start Automatically" checkbox in option 4:
http://spdevlab.com/2013/06/20/embedding-video-apps-and-leveraging-_layouts15videoembedplayer-aspx-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: The trick is to not add auto="1" as a new property to the <video> or <iframe> tag, but directly add &auto=1 as an extra parameter in the src property.

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML5 Video control to show media, which have lot of inbuilt functionalities like autoplay, preload, loop, poster and many other etc.

```
<video controls autoplay width="320">
    <source src="<MEDIA_URL>" />          
</video>
```